# How to use Java 19 in IntelliJ Idea community Edition

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to use the destructuring syntax of Java 19 pattern match, but my IntelliJ Idea cannot understand it (please refer below screenshot). Is there a way to fix this? Or IntellJ is not yet ready for java 19 ?

[image]

```java
    // sealed interface and record combo
    public sealed interface LoginRequest permits DefaultLogin {}
    public record DefaultLogin(@Min(1) int userId, @Valid Password password) implements LoginRequest {}

    // java 19 switch is not supported in IntelliJ Idea, gives all red lines
    Optional<Profile> profileMaybe = switch (loginRequest) {
        case DefaultLogin(int id, Password pw) -> getProfile(new ById(id));
```

Answer (score 2):

## IntelliJ 2022.3

The [early-access version of IntelliJ 2022.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2022.3/supported-java-versions.html) does support Java 19 as an “experimental feature”. This `.3` update of IntelliJ should be formally released very soon.

This support includes the third preview of the pattern-matching with `switch` feature. As a [preview feature](https://openjdk.org/jeps/12), you’ll need to go out of your way to enable that functionality. And note that this feature is also previewed in Java 20, so details may be changing.

For details on the feature, see:

- [*JEP 427: Pattern Matching for switch (Third Preview)*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/427) (Java 19)
- [*JEP 433: Pattern Matching for switch (Fourth Preview)*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/433) (Java 20)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support Java 19 yet. See [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/supported-java-versions.html).

Comment: That page is currently incorrect, because IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 does support Java 19.

Comment: The page has now been updated to show the correct information that 2022.2 has Java 19 support. Of course for the most complete support it is better to use 2022.3.